# Why function as an object property not accessing the closure when object is created using 'new' and returned immediately?

Tags: javascript, closures, javascript-objects

Now I am calling `data()` function which will create a local variable `x` and return object created together with `obj` function and `new` keyword,which has property `fun` whose value is another function.Then why returned `fun` method is not accessing closure `x`?

```
var obj=function(){
    this.fun=function(){
        console.log(x);
    };
};

var data=function(){
    var x=5;
    return new obj();
};

var y=data();
y.fun();
```

Now instead of creating new object we just place same object and return it.
Now it has access to closure `x`.Why?

```
var data=function(){
    var x=5;
    return {
        fun:function(){
            console.log(x);
        }
    };
};

var y=data();
y.fun();
```

Comment: `x` is nowhere in the *literal scope* of `this.fun`. How about you simply pass it as argument to `new obj`?! `var obj = function (x) ...`

Comment: Flipping your question on it's head, why do you think `x` _should_ be available in `this.fun` in the first code block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a closure is based on where a function is **created**.

```
// It has access to any x in this scope
var obj=function(){
    // It has access to any x in this scope
    this.fun=function(){
        // It has access to any x in this scope
        console.log(x);
    };
};
```

… but you have defined X here:

```
var data=function(){
    // New scope here and none of the earlier code has access to it
    var x=5;
    return new obj();
};
```

… and only functions where the function expression or declaration is *inside* the anonymous function expression you have there can access `x`.

You could pass `x` as an argument to `obj` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your second example the function was created in the same scope as the variable and so had access to it.  In the first example,  no x existed when the function was defined.